# Angular Directive How can we pass binding attr

Tags: angularjs

Assuming that we have custom directive which have ng-repeat inside:

```
//...    
<div class="item" ng-repeat="item in items" data-value="{{item.id}}">
        {{item.name}}
    </div>
//...
```

And the caller is:

```
<dropdown items="assetTypesData"></dropdown>
```

Question is how can we pass `name` and `id` of `{{item.name}}` and `{{item.id}}` to directive as:

```
<dropdown items="assetTypesData" text="name" value="id"></dropdown>
```

Comment: You want to pass the value to directive on click event or something right. Like suppose I am repeating students in a table format then to delete a student I must pass student's id to the function.

Comment: Hi @RanganathanSwamy, actually I want to pass property name of item in list and ng-repeat will get data from them

Comment: That means in ng-repeat division you would like to have item's id, item's name both right? If that is the case you have to make a place for that as well in the directive.

Comment: It's almost close. I mean how can pass dynamic property to ng-repeat from the caller to let it know which property it should get to render. In this case is id and name

Comment: Like I pass Id, it will get item.id, name, it will get item.name or address, it will get item.address

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using isolate scope, you can pass in the three things you need: items, text, id. Then in your template, reference the `{{item[text]}}` for getting the property passed in for text (name in this exmaple) and `{{item[value]}}` to get the value property on the item (e.g. id).

```js
angular.module('myApp', [])
  .controller('MainController', function ($scope) {
    var vm = {};
    $scope.vm = vm;
  
    activate();
  
    function activate() {
      var items = [];
      for (var i = 0; i <= 15; ++i) {
        items.push({id: i, name: 'Item ' + i});
      }
      
      vm.items = items;
    }
  })

  .directive('myDropdown', function () {
    var template = '<div class="item" ng-repeat="item in items" data-value="{{item[value]}}">' +
        '{{item[text]}}' +
    '</div>';
  
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      template: template,
      scope: {
        items: '=',
        text: '@',
        value: '@'
      }
    }
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MainController">
  <my-dropdown items="vm.items" text="name" value="id"></my-dropdown>  
</div>
```

Comment: Thank so much @Patrick, now I know more about how to use @ and &